How to implement drag and drop on a table list with pagination in angular?
I have a table with ngb-pagination and now I have a requirement to add drag and drop in the list.I am not able to drag an item from page 1 and drop that item in page 2. Is that possible to do it. How can I do that?
I am expecting an answer where it helps me to code so that I can drag an item from list in page one and drop it in page 2 and vice versa in angular.

please share the minimal reproducible code

I don't think it's possible, drag & drop only works with elements on screen.
